# Chrome extension side bar

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension that will show a permanent side bar and shrink the tab content to the rest of the browser tab width.

I know this is possible as "Tidy Sidebar" is doing it: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tidy-sidebar/dgmacifhhpefamjmolpipkijcofcmbgp?hl=en

I have looked through stackoverflow and the extension API but all I can find is popup code.

Comment: Judging by the screenshots, it looks that the extension just resizes the browser's window. Maybe [`chrome.windows.update`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-update) specifying window's height and width.

Comment: Yes, it just opens an additional window and resizes the main one.

Comment: ok that's not what I'm looking for, is there a way for me to show a proper side panel ?

Answer (score 1):

This could be done:

Using `chrome.windows.update` you can resize the current window with a given position and size (width, height).

Then using `chrome.windows.create` you can create a new window with a given position, size and address. Then you can inject any script you'd like into that new Chrome window's tab.

So you could resize and position the current window so that you have 200px on the left side of the window. Then create a new window 200px wide with position (0, 0) on the screen.